# CSS: How can I remove the extra white space caused by a line break in a link?

Tags: html, css

**Edit 2:** My time is short, so I will be using dippas' suggestion of using an actual image instead of a background. I'm keeping this question open just in case someone has a better solution. Thank you for all the help!

**Original Question/Problem:**

I have been Googling for the solution for an hour now, to no avail!

I am formatting a site to responsive and several long links that contain a background image aren't breaking correctly. I've tried *float: left*, *display: block*, *display: inline-block* and none of them work. The closest thing I got to a fix is setting it to *display: inline*, but I would rather have the background image to the side instead of right next to the last word.

This is my first time personally consulting this website (I have used your solutions to get out of ruts many times before, so thank you!), so I cannot post images, but here's a rough fiddle example (**Edit:** here's a new fiddle since the other one had a defined div width):

http://jsfiddle.net/2e28fanq/22/

(I want to get rid of that extra space between the arrow and "Educational")

**CSS:**

```
a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 40px;
    background: url('Arrow-Right.png') 100% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Here is a crude illustration of what I need it to do:

```
Register for a FREE Educational >
Webinar
```

And what it's doing instead:

```
Register for a FREE Educational          >
Webinar
```

Seeing as it happens in JSFiddle, too, I doubt it has anything to do with the rest of my code. I cannot link to the site in question due to confidentiality/contract reasons, but I hope someone here can help me out with what I am able to provide. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

One simple solution is to use [`word-break: break-all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break):

```css
.wrap {
  width: 425px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 40px;
  background: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Tabs_Color_Social/40/Arrow-Right.png') 100% 50% no-repeat;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> <a href="#">Register for a FREE Educational Webinar</a>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2e28fanq/2/)

This works for a long text too:

```css
.wrap {
  width: 425px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-right: 40px;
  background: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Tabs_Color_Social/40/Arrow-Right.png') 100% 50% no-repeat;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap"> <a href="#">Register for a FREE Educational Webinar asdasd asd asd asda as Register for a FREE Educational Webinar asdasd asd asd asda as </a>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

[**fiddle example with long text**](http://jsfiddle.net/2e28fanq/3/)

Comment: Very close! Is there a way to keep the words intact, though?

Comment: Agreed. This doesn't seem like a solution at all because it breaks words in the middle, which is really unnatural and seemingly unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

That extra space isn't a bug coming from nowhere.

It appears simply because you set the background position to be at `100% 50%`, which means 100% from the left and 50% from the top. Since the width of your `a` is `425px` (because the parent's width is `425px` and the child is `display: block`, which takes 100% of available width) and your arrow is sticking to the right end, there will obviously be a gap between the right side of the text and the left side of the image.

If the `background-position-x` value were not 100%, or the width of the parent was not `425px`, things would be different, as shown in the below two examples.

- http://jsfiddle.net/2e28fanq/15/
- http://jsfiddle.net/2e28fanq/8/

Comment: No dice; the arrow still moves behind the text when I remove the defined div width and resize the Result window.

Comment: I seem to be failing to understand the basic issue. You want to implement a responsive solution where the arrow always 'almost' sticks to the text?

Comment: seems like that, if so it is better to use img instead background

Comment: Yes (unfortunately, I would leave it as is, but this is a request from the client/QA). Here is a better fiddle that demonstrates my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/2e28fanq/22/ I'm aiming to eliminate that extra space when "Webinar" moves down to the 2nd line.

Comment: then use media queries

Comment: @dippas Wow, I didn't think to do that instead (using img instead of a background)! It may be just what I need to do.

Comment: An absolutely positioned image with the parent positioned relatively will do the job, with proper z-indexes.

Answer (score 1):

**Change the padding: 15px; to the anchor**. **Add margin-right: 40px;**.

**UPDATE:**

*background-clip not neccesary...*

```
.wrap {
    width: 425px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding: 15px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
    background: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Tabs_Color_Social/40/Arrow-Right.png') 100% center no-repeat;
    background-clip: border-box;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

[image]

[image]

See: http://jsfiddle.net/abrhmcc/75ybzLnz/3/

Change the width of wrap to make tests.

The **padding-right:40px;** is to **avoid text and arrow overlaping**, you can change it to reduce the distance between the arrow and the text.

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to do it without a fixed width?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this?

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
    <a href="#">Register for a FREE Educational Webinar</a>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.wrap {
    display:inline;
    width:auto;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
a {
    width: auto;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    padding-right: 40px;
    background: url('https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Tabs_Color_Social/40/Arrow-Right.png') 100% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v8ngz46r/)

Comment: Not at all! I want the arrow to hug the side when it line breaks, not hug the last word. I'd like it to stay to the right and middle-aligned, but without the huge space caused by the line break.

Comment: OK, I don't understand what "hug" is, but I'm referring to your question and removing your space plus your info on "working on responsive layout", thus I came with a solution about that. Try http://jsfiddle.net/wt1jfego/ for a more or less similar approach, but then again, it's related to responsive layout (resize the fiddle and see what happens, your 2 lines are just random, you might have one or 2 lines or even 3, that's why it's called RESPONSIVE), so if this is not what you mean, then I have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: edit: based on your comment on Alex Char's answer now I see what you want is NON RESPONSIVE, which is the absolute opposite to your question's description, hence the absolute opposite to what I was doing. This answer won't work

Comment: I'm aware that the line count will vary depending on screen size. My concern is that when a word moves to a new line, there is extra space added to the right as if the word were still there and I'm trying to find a way to remove that space.