# Prevent adding a space in style-formatted HTML <sup> tag

Tags: html

Hello Stack Community,

I've already tried sever solutions but nothing works for me.

I have following construct in HTML:

```html
<div>
<span>Some quite long text that I'd love to separate drom sup element<sup>Sup content</sup></span>
</div>
```

After applying some basic formatting:

```html
<div>
    <span>
      Some quite long text that I'd love to separate drom sup element
      <sup>Sup content</sup>
    </span>
</div>
```

The space is rendered in between `element` and `Sup`, ight in a place, where enter was pasted. How can I gracefully prevent this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS: How can I remove the extra white space caused by a line break in a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26186024/css-how-can-i-remove-the-extra-white-space-caused-by-a-line-break-in-a-link)

Answer (score 2):

Write **sup** tag in **same line** as span text

```
<div>
    <span>
      Some quite long text that I'd love to separate drom sup element<sup>Sup content</sup>
    </span>
</div>
```